# Python logger throws KeyError for custom logger inputs while using logger adapter

Tags: python, logging

```
[logger_main]
level=INFO
handlers=file_handler
qualname=main
propagate=0

[handler_file_handler]
class=FileHandler
formatter=formatter
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
maxBytes=31457280
level=DEBUG
args=('../log/logfile.txt',)

[formatter_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(RequestNumber)s - %(funcName)-20s() - %(levelname)-10s - %(message)s
format=%(asctime)s - %(RequestNumber)s - %(funcName)-20s() - %(levelname)-10s - %(message)s
```

In Python I am using the logger adapter to update the request number in each log written to  file:

```
log = logging.LoggerAdapter(logging.getLogger('main'), {"RequestNumber" : requestNum()});
```

Error thrown: Below is the traceback of error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 861, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 734, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 469, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'RequestNumber'
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
>>> formatter = logging.Formatter('%(customid)s %(message)s')
>>> handler = logging.StreamHandler()
>>> handler.setFormatter(formatter)
>>> logger.addHandler(handler)
>>> adapter = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, {'customid': 'foo'})
>>> adapter.warning('test')
foo test
```

Comment: My code creates teh log and inserts the RequestNumber successfully in each log but throws the error mentioned in the post

Comment: @MANOJ then you should post a short standalone script which demonstrates the error.